# cmd login page is not displaying

Tags: 13.04, login, raid, console

I have configured Raid 1 and installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my IBM server. After the installation and rebooting, the login screen is not appearing, and it is going to pre-boot analysis page. I don't know how to get to the login screen by typing a command at the command prompt. Please help me.

Comment: Reddy garu : to help you more we need information like what is the text you are getting while its booting. try to capture an image,:)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can move to CLI based login with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Then it will r3edirected to CLI based login page where you can login with your username and password.

Comment: I am already done that but I am still redirecting to preboot page

Comment: Thanks for your reply raja shekar, I have 2 servers in one server it installed witout any problem, but in this server I followed same process but I don't know whats the problem, after installation of operating system and rebooting it is directly taking me to preboot page. After that I am not able to do any thing.

Comment: @SandeepReddyChama ok reddy garu , please provide the information about your server specifications.